# Woocommerce Calculate amount by customer input in product page

Tags: wordpress

In product page to get input from customer as number of words. To calculate the amount from products add-ons fixed amount to additional 10$ for each above 500 words.

ex: 1. Number of Words: 530
Normal Price + additional price: 180$ + 10$
Total: 190$

2. Number of Words: 1040
   Normal Price + additional price: 180$ + 20$
   Total: 200$

This process as to create dynamic input form customer to calculate amount the price and total amount.

```
`$extra_amount = (int)'10';
$amount = (int)'180'; // how to get amount from woocommerce data
if(isset($_POST['wordnumber'])){ // how to get this paramater form woocommerce post values
$test =$_POST['wordnumber'];
$original_amount = '';
    if($test <= (int)'500'){
        $original_amount = $amount;
    }
    elseif($test > (int)'500'){
        $div_amount = $test/(int)'500';
        $round = floor($div_amount);
        //echo '<br/>';
        $total_extra = $round*$extra_amount;
        $original_amount = $amount+$total_extra;
    }
    echo $original_amount;
}`
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we could help you exactly!

Comment: this is my code i try to embedded to this into woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed WC Fields Factory plugin then i got value from one field using key. in that i written a function and i overrided the price value.

```
function calculate_gift_wrap_fee( $cart_object ) {
/* Gift wrap price */
$additionalPrice = 10;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {  
             $test = $value['custom field'];
               if( $test <= 100 ) {
                   $quantity = floatval( $value['quantity'] );
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
                    $value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice );
                }
                elseif( $test > 100 ) {
                    $div_amount = floatval($test/500);
                    $round = floor($div_amount);
                    $total_extra = floatval($round * $additionalPrice); 
                    $quantity = floatval( $value['quantity'] );
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
                    $pp = ($value['price']);
                    $total = floatval($pp + $total_extra);
                    $value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $total );
                }       
    }}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', calculate_gift_wrap_fee', 1, 1 );
```